# JSP wouldn't compile

Tags: jsp

```
<HTML>
<BODY>
Hello!  The time is now <%= new java.util.Date() %>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

I tried to open this trivial jsp file with firefox, but the expression wouldn't evaluate. I have Java installed.

I'm new to JSP. Should I put the jsp in some specific directory? Or do I forget to include anything in the jsp file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like that you aren't using a JSP/Servlet container at all but instead just opened the file straight from local disk file system by a `file://` URL. This is indeed not going to work. You need to install a JSP/Servlet container. This is basically a HTTP web server which has the JSP compiler builtin and supports serving JSP/Servlets. A well known example is [Apache Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org). Just [download](http://tomcat.apache.org/download-70.cgi) the zip under "Core" section (no, not the "Windows zip", really just "zip") and extract it on your disk. Then perform the following steps:

1. Create a new subfolder in `/webapps` folder of Tomcat.
2. Put the JSP file in that folder.
3. Start Tomcat by the `/bin/startup.bat` (Windows) or `/bin/startup.sh` (Unix) script.
4. Go in your browser to http://localhost:8080/foldername/yourfile.jsp where "foldername" is the name of the folder you created in step 1 and "yourfile.jsp" is the filename of the JSP you placed in step 2.

#### See also:

- [Our JSP wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsp/info)
- [Coreservlets.com JSP/Servlet tutorials](http://courses.coreservlets.com/Course-Materials/csajsp2.html)

Answer (score 1):

A JSP is evaluated by a web container like Tomcat or Jetty, and the HTML that it generates is then sent to the browser. The browser can't run a JSP on its own.

Answer (score 0):

Check your project library settings and that your java lib is in the class PATH.

Answer (score 0):

Each jsp page must be compiled to a servlet by a JSP engine. Firefox is not a JSP engine. Have a look at [JavaServer Pages Technology](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/tutorial/1_3-fcs/doc/JSPIntro.html) which might be helpful to you.